# How to generate JSON object using SQL functions in oracle12c release1?

Tags: oracle

I am in a need to develop a procedure to return JSON object in oracle 12c release 1. The below is the exact version I am using.
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

Could any one you guide me if we have any default inbuilt functions to generate JSON object in this oracle version?

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the format you want, you can use `JSON_OBJECT` or `JSON_ARRAY` in your select, with as parameter the list of columns.
If your question is about storing JSON data, you can use a CLOB column and add a check constraint with `IS JSON`

edit: my bad, it's since release 2. For release 1 : https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/json-support-in-oracle-database-12cr1

Comment: I gone through release 1 documentation but I am struggling to find the way to generate JSON from the SQL results. May I know where can I find that in that release 1 document?